# Issues with nginx basic_auth exemption

Tags: nginx, authentication

I'm trying to exempt a location from basic_auth whereas the rest of the site does require it. Reading up on it my config should work but for some reason it still returns 401 for /asd/qwe/.

```
server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    root /var/www/domains/domain.com/htdocs/public;

    index index.php index.htm;

    location / {
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.domain.com.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domains/domain.com/htdocs/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

      auth_basic "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /var/www/domains/htpasswd/domain.com.htpasswd;

    }

    location /asd/qwe/ {
          auth_basic off;
          allow all;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.domain.com.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domains/domain.com/htdocs/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finnaly found a solution to it:

```
server {
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
  root /var/www/domains/domain.com/htdocs/public;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domains/domain.com/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/domains/domain.com/error.log;

  index index.php index.htm;

  auth_basic_user_file /var/www/domains/htpasswd/domain.com.htpasswd;

  location ~ /.svn/ {
      deny all;
  }

  location ~ /.htaccess {
      deny all;
  }

  location ^~ /psp/callback/ {
        auth_basic off;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.domain.com.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domains/domain.com/htdocs/public$fastcgi_script_name;
   }

  location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.domain.com.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domains/domain.com/htdocs/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

  # Zend Framework rewrite
  if (!-e $request_filename) {
      set $zfRewrite 1;
  }
  if ($zfRewrite = 1) {
      rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
  }
}
```

Comment: Framework rewrite is the key!  I had an issue with Laravel code base. The whole site is locked with auth_basic, while just two URLs were allowed.  Auth exclude worked fine, but laravel was not able to route the URL which is a not a physically existing path. Framework rewrite mentioned above resolved the issue.  Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using literal matches (the = location prefix), processing stops at the first match.  Put your /asd/qwe block above the / block and it should work.

For more information, see the nginx documentation on the location directive:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: Forgot to mention I've the following in the end as well which I think is the source of the issue:

 if (!-e $request_filename) {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  set $zfRewrite 1;
 }
        if ($zfRewrite = 1) {
  rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
 }